# Apache Camel - Filname to process

Tags: apache-camel, processor

I have a route , that is downloading a file from FTP. After that I just would like to send the filename to a jms:queue and not anything else. Ho to do that?

Actually I have this route

```
<from uri="ftp://ftp.x.com?username=x&amp;password=x&amp;binary=true&amp;stepwise=false&amp;delay=20000"    />
<to uri="file://{{download_folder}}?fileName=${date:file:yyyyMMdd}_${file:name}&amp;keepLastModified=true"  /> 
<to uri="processFileNameToBody" />
<to uri="jms:queue:File.Process" />
```

with this in processFileNameToBody (org.apache.camel.Processor)

```
 public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        try {
            if (exchange.getIn() instanceof GenericFileMessage) {               
                log.info("Starting Processing FileName to body");
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String file = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileNameProduced");
                map.put("file", file);
                XStream xs = new XStream();
                String xml = xs.toXML(map);
                exchange.getOut().setBody(xml);     
                log.info("Finished Processing FileName to body:" + file);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

but it does not work. I got a NPE in GenericFileConverter.convert.to

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: RemoteFile[
```

Perhaps anybody has a solution for this. It can't be so complicated, but actually I fail. I think it has something to do when the file is written. It is writte at the end, but I already changed the body.

Help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<from uri="ftp://ftp.x.com?username=x&amp;password=x&amp;binary=true&amp;stepwise=false&amp;delay=20000"    />
<to uri="file://{{download_folder}}?fileName=${date:file:yyyyMMdd}_${file:name}&amp;keepLastModified=true"  /> 
<setBody><simple>${header.CamelFileNameProduced}</simple></setBody>
<to uri="jms:queue:File.Process" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works. But why do that solution differ from my process. Is it the <simple> or where exactly is the difference?

Comment: Well, in your processor I am not sure why are you doing all the XML stuff. But for doing the same you should do `exchange.getIn().setBody((String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileNameProduced"))`. Read more about In and Out in the camel docs :)

Comment: The xml stuff was for later processes. Then it was more easier sending them to jms. I now do it direct in the route. Thank you.